# simple plot with beta and confidence intervals

Tags: r

I calculated beta, and CIs for a regression model.

```
            beta  CI_2.5pct  CI_97.5pct 
FCC3<75m     20  10  30
FCC375-150m  40  35  45
FCC3150-300m 25  15  35
```

And I was asked to generate a plot with these three points like this.

[image]

I'm using R, and can anyone tell me how to do it? It not necessary to be exact same as the figure above, as long as it can interpret the results is ok. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: start with `?plot'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
beta  CI_2.5pct  CI_97.5pct 
FCC3<75m     20  10  30
FCC375-150m  40  35  45
FCC3150-300m 25  15  35  

x <- read.table(con <- file("clipboard"), header = T) # please use dput next time

library(Hmisc)
with(x,errbar(x$beta,x$beta,x$CI_97.5pct,x$CI_2.5pct))
grid(nx=NA,ny=NULL)
```

[image]